# Using BSCAN_SIME2

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, jtag

I have instantiated the BSCANE2 in my tutorial designs in order to do easy controls and commands into the trial designs, and in order to simulate this I will use the BSCAN_SIME2.
However, I do not seem to find any documentation on this SIME2.

My trials so far on simulating has shown that it does set the SHIFT signal when going through the DR Shift states, but I have not yet been able to get a SEL signal from issuing a USER1 JTAG instruction.

Anyone had success using this simulation component?

Up until now I have just used very simple structures in my test bench. I dont want to build a larger design before I know exactly how to stimulate it.

Thanks.

Comment: got my success now so no longer need an answer.

Comment: you could provide the answer in case anyone else has the same question.

Comment: It is now long ago i found my solution, but my problem was actually that the SVF file i referenced in a SVF simulation player could not go so deep in my files and used one i didn't expect.

Comment: Using following worked for me:
<blink>
  CMDREG_CTRL : BSCANE2 
    generic map ( JTAG_CHAIN => 1 ) 
    port map ( 
      CAPTURE => CREG_CAP,
      DRCK => CREG_DRCK,
      RESET => CREG_TAPRESET,
      RUNTEST => CREG_TAPRUNTEST,
      SEL => CREG_ENA,
      SHIFT => CREG_SHIFT,
      TCK => CREG_TCK,
      TDI => CREG_TDI,
      TMS => CREG_TMS, 
      UPDATE => CREG_UPD,
      TDO => CREG_TDO
  );
<\blink>

Comment: Then the SVF simulator testbench exercize the signals using:
  component JTAG_SIME2
  generic (
    PART_NAME : string := "7A20"
  );
  port (
    TDO : out std_logic;
    TCK : in std_logic;
    TDI : in std_logic;
    TMS : in std_logic
  );
  end component;